# Does anyone know of a library for creating Speakable Items in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4.2

I have been looking in the documentation, but have found nothing so far to help me create Speakable Items in Xcode 4.... AppleScript and Automator the only supported methods?

Does anyone out there in the ether have any suggestions (besides RTFD, which I am actively pursuing..?)

;)

TIA!

Regards,

Steve O'Sullivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to tap into the Accessiblility framework for speakable items then I'm sorry to say you're out of luck. There is no direct support (that I know of) in iOS for TextToSpeech. However there are a number of open source TTS engines you could use. Flite is a C based TTS engine and can be run on the iPhone. Even better would be to look into the OpenEars project which integrates Flight and Sphinx Lite for voice recognition. (not sure if it's actually called Sphinx Lite but looking on the Sphinx web site would give you clarity.) Another option would be to use a Client/Server approach where you would host a TTS engine on a web server and make calls from the client. It could be as simple as opening a URL request to the web server in the form of "http://myserver/tts?say=How+Do+You+Do". Take the response stream and plug it into an instance of the AVPlayer and you're off and running.